# How do I turn a meal order code into stats that a human can read in java?

Tags: java

Pretty simple question, even though it looks long.

I am supposed to write a java code that accepts an input of something like "021250040625Pat John" and turn it into 02 adult meals at 12.50 each (first 6 numbers say that) 4 child meals at 06.25 each (second six) name is Pat John.

I have to total it and add discount but I can do all that,   '         . Any and all help welcome, I'm new to java but understand the basics. Just need help with reading those individual numbers and letters in the input code.

I already have the basics of the code laid out and this// (result is a placeholder)

```
  Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter your order code: ");
  orderCode = userInput.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("Name: " + result);
  System.out.println("Adult meals: " + result);
  System.out.println("Child meals: " + result);
  System.out.println("Subtotal: " + result);
  System.out.println("15% Discount: " + result);
  System.out.println("Total: " + result);
```

Comment: "021250040625Pat John" is not a `double`. Read it as a `String`. Then you can use `substring` to pull out the individual parts by their position. And `Integer.parseInt` to turn substrings into numbers.

Comment: oh ok thank you I figured it was a string, just layed out basic code didn't really try anything yet. I'll look up exactly how to use substring but this is what I needed. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: You just need to go through that number once.. so no need for loops. Out of the string the first 12 chars contain all info but the name. So name is str.substing(11, str.lenght). Parsing the first part is similar. But you might need to covert to ints or double. Of you need the last 4 digits you can do mod 10000 and it'll give you that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`Scanner#nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) to get the order code, and [`String#substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) to get the individual numbers. You can convert the numbers from `String` to `int` using [`Integer.praseInt(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-):

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter your order code: ");
// Get the entire code using Scanner.nextLine() instead of Scanner.nextDouble()
String code = userInput.nextLine();

// Get the first two characters (the adult meals)
int adultMeals = Integer.parseInt(code.substring(0, 2));
// Get the next four characters separated by a period (the price)
double price = Double.parseDouble(code.substring(2, 4) + "." + code.substring(4, 6));
// Get the next two characters (the child meals)
int childMeals = Integer.parseInt(code.substring(7, 8));
// Get the next four characters separated by a period (the child price)
double childPrice = Double.parseDouble(code.substring(8, 10) + "." + code.substring(10, 12));

/*
 * To calculate the subtotal, multiple the adult price by the number of adult
 * meals, and the child price by the number of child meals, then add the two
 * together.
 */
double subtotal = (price * adultMeals) + (childPrice * childMeals);
// The discount is 15% of the subtotal
double discount = subtotal * 0.15;
// Subtract the discount to get the total
double total = subtotal - discount;

String name = code.substring(12);

System.out.println("Name: " + name);
System.out.println("Adult meals: " + adultMeals);
System.out.println("Child meals: " + childMeals);
System.out.println("Subtotal: " + subtotal);
System.out.println("15% Discount: " + discount);
System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much. I was looking up how to use it and I came back and saw this. Huge help thanks for quick response since it is due tonight.

Comment: Alright just finished, and I can't thank you enough. I had a few more things to hit in order to get full points so I had to change the code quite a bit. If you want to see what I was going for check this out: http://pastiebin.com/embed/5c5520c8a3e11                    I had to add an if statement just incase the message was wrong and had to add some decimal format shit but otherwise, I couldn't have done it without you.

Comment: Last thing, when you did child meals, I think you meant to do code.substring(6, 8) instead of 7, 8. If someone ordered like 12 child meals it wouldn't properly output (they would be getting a really good deal if they ordered 90 meals)

Comment: @GraysonPhillips happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to read the meal code as a String, then use `substring` method in order to cut it up in sections. This will work as long as your meal codes follow the same scheme. You will end up with small strings that you can parse as integers or doubles. There are a few ways to handle the lack of decimal points in the prices, like dividing by the amount of precision you want (100 for 2 decimals).

The adult meal part would look something like this:

```
int numAdultMeals = Integer.parseInt(orderCode.substring(0, 2));
double adultMealPrice = Double.parseDouble(orderCode.substring(2, 6)) / 100.0;
```

Comment: Good short, concise answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

check out javas substring method... you can then divide the input into different variables.
alternatively, store the input to a char array, then grab the items you want from that array using there indexes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your input is positional, meaning the first two characters are the quantity, the next four the price, etc.

If that is the case you can use `String.substring` to divide the string (as in `substring(0,2)` to get the first two characters). Then use `Double.parseDouble()` to convert them into numbers (or maybe `Integer.parseInt()` for the quantities).

You will need to divide the prices by 100 after converting them.